# Checkboxes with join table and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, simple-form

I have a Users table, Activities table, and UserActvities join table. Activities resources are nested under User resources. I want to allow a user to select multiple activities at once so that they can be stored as activities that they prefer in the join table. How do I set this up using simple form? I have tried variation of the following in the activity index view but keep getting an error:

```
<%= simple_form_for @activities do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :activities, collection: Activity.all, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a form for `user`(notice `@user` instead of `@activities`), since activities is a relation on user model

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :activities, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now get the following error however: Failure/Error: click_link 'Activities List'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: You would have to intialize @user in your controller action.

Comment: still getting the same error. Will report back when I figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: so I had to use current_user in the form (using Devise) and also my test had not created any activities to select from so that contributed to the error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the correct syntax for simple form ([docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations))

```
<%= f.association :activities, as: :check_boxes, 
          collection: Activity.all %>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I now get the following error however, any thoughts? Thank for the help. I now get the following error however: Failure/Error: click_link 'Activities List'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class